Need help in finding analog of these tweaks on linux
     ::Enable Hardware Accelerated Scheduling
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers" /v "HwSchMode" && reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers" /v "HwSchMode" /t Reg_DWORD /d "2" /f
::Enable gdi hardware acceleration
for /f %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class" /v "VgaCompatible" /s ^| findstr "HKEY"') do reg add "%%a" /v "KMD_EnableGDIAcceleration" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f
::Enable GameMode
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\GameBar" /v "AllowAutoGameMode" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\GameBar" /v "AutoGameModeEnabled" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f
::FSO
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_FSEBehaviorMode" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_FSEBehavior" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_HonorUserFSEBehaviorMode" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_DXGIHonorFSEWindowsCompatible" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_EFSEFeatureFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
reg add "HKCU\System\GameConfigStore" /v "GameDVR_DSEBehavior" /t REG_DWORD /d "2" /f
::Disable GpuEnergyDrv
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\GpuEnergyDrv" /v "Start" /t Reg_DWORD /d "4" /f
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\GpuEnergyDr" /v "Start" /t Reg_DWORD /d "4" /f
::Disable Preemption
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Scheduler" /v "EnablePreemption" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f


reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "3D_Refresh_Rate_Override_DEF" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "3to2Pulldown_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AAF_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "Adaptive De-interlacing" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowRSOverlay" /t Reg_SZ /d "false" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSkins" /t Reg_SZ /d "false" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSnapshot" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AllowSubscription" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AntiAlias_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AreaAniso_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "ASTT_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "AutoColorDepthReduction_NA" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableSAMUPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableUVDPowerGatingDynamic" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableVCEPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableAspmL0s" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableAspmL1" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps_NA" /t Reg_SZ /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_DeLagEnabled" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_FRTEnabled" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableDMACopy" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableBlockWrite" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "StutterMode" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "EnableUlps" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "PP_SclkDeepSleepDisable" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "PP_ThermalAutoThrottlingEnable" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "DisableDrmdmaPowerGating" /t Reg_DWORD /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%" /v "KMD_EnableComputePreemption" /t Reg_DWORD /d "0" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Main3D_DEF" /t Reg_SZ /d "1" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Main3D" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "FlipQueueSize" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "ShaderCache" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Tessellation_OPTION" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "Tessellation" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3100" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "VSyncControl" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3000" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\UMD" /v "TFQ" /t Reg_BINARY /d "3200" /f >nul 2>&1
reg add "%REGPATH_AMD%\DAL2_DATA__2_0\DisplayPath_4\EDID_D109_78E9\Option" /v "ProtectionControl" /t Reg_BINARY /d "0100000001000000" /f >nul 2>&1

i cant get GPU working normally but on windows this script helped me. but i cant find similar tweaks on linux. Any ideas?

There's absolutely no parallel to that on Linux. The problems this solves are specific to the windows 3D drivers, which you aren't using.
